# Error in mysql_insert_id() [MAIL TAG]

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

```
     $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
     $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
     $headers .= 'From: contact@email.com';
     $to = $email;
     $subject = "Confirmation";
     $message = "Hi, $username. You're registred in Site. Link for confirmation:     http://site.com/confirm/**".mysql_insert_id()."**";
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
     $query = mysql_query("insert into usr_users(username, password, email, avator, pin)          values('$username', '$password', '$email', '$img', '$pin')");
     $query2 = mysql_query("insert into usr_confirm(user_name, user_id, active, data) values('$username', '".mysql_insert_id()."', '$active', '$senha')");
     echo"Success!</br>";
```

The second **mysql_insert_id()** (line 9) is correct! But the first mysql_insert_id() (line 6) return 0 in e-mail box.

Comment: You can't call mysql_insert_id on line 6 if you've not previously inserted a record - I assume you're after the the insert into `usr_users`?

Comment: re-order your code and you will be fine; run the query first then you send the email, the id will be available;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id), `mysql_insert_id()` will return `0` if the last statement doesn't generate an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value:

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, **0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value**, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

You're first using the `mysql_insert_id()` call *before* you've inserted any records, so the result has to be `0` (unless there's a call before this somewhere else in your code -t hen you'd actually be getting skewed results). Try moving your mail-related calls to below your insert statements, giving you:

```
// insert the records
$query = mysql_query("insert into usr_users(username, password, email, avator, pin)          values('$username', '$password', '$email', '$img', '$pin')");
$query2 = mysql_query("insert into usr_confirm(user_name, user_id, active, data) values('$username', '".mysql_insert_id()."', '$active', '$senha')");

// send the email
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: contact@email.com';
$to = $email;
$subject = "Confirmation";
$message = "Hi, $username. You're registred in Site. Link for confirmation:     http://site.com/confirm/**".mysql_insert_id()."**";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo"Success!</br>";
```

If you still receive the error after this change, you will need to confirm that your primary-key field on the `usr_confirm` table is correctly configured with `auto_increment`. Also, if it is setup properly, try passing the connection-variable to the function, such as `mysql_insert_id($conn);` where `$conn` is the result of your `mysql_connect()` call.

*Site note* (not answer specific)
Your code is *extremely* prone to SQL Injection; you're not escaping *any* of the values. Rather than go into what SQL Injection is, I would much rather direct you to use Prepared Statements.

In addition, PHP is deprecating the `mysql_` methods in favor for the [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) methods. Both of these support prepared statements and I would recommend for you to look into these.

In the interim, please consider wrapping your variables with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, such as:

```
... values ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "', ...
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he's calling mysql_insert_id before he does the insert statement, to generate the text of the email.

Comment: @andrewsi Ah, my bad entirely - I read the `mysql_insert_id()` call from the `$query2 = ` line, I didn't even see it in the `$message =` line. Updating answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made the query until after send the email, `mysql_insert_id` gives the The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query, so you'll have to put query one berfore you use `mysql_insert_id`